# Injecting and using Spring Security UserCache

Tags: caching, spring-security, spring-boot

Spring Boot here. I am implementing my own `UserDetailsService` impl and need to reference/use the Spring-provided `UserCache`:

```
package myorg.myapp;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserCache;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Resource
    private UserCache userCache;

    ...
}
```

When I go to run my app I get the following exception message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of
type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserCache] found for dependency: expected at
least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER,
type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
```

**Any ideas why Spring can't find a `UserCache` bean?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to implement a [UserCache](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserCache.html) as a @Bean somewhere in your code.

The [NullUserCache](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/cache/NullUserCache.html) is a 'fake' one that doesn't actually cache anything.  Look at the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/cache/NullUserCache.java).

The [SpringCacheBasedUserCache](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/cache/SpringCacheBasedUserCache.html) is probably what you want.  It requires a [Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) to be passed in the [constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/cache/SpringCacheBasedUserCache.java).  This cache can be something like a [ConcurrentMapCache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCache.html), EhCacheCache, or JCacheCache.

I find the ConcurrentMapCache great for local development.

I don't use the UserCache in anything I'm currently working on but here's my config for Object caching.  In this @Configuration file you'll see 2 profiles, one for local dev and one for aws deployments. Hopefully this will get you going - https://gist.github.com/denov/021e9c736d15b1fc56c3e8d185b8ef15

Comment: Thanks @denov (+1) - two quick followup questions, if you don't mind: **(1)** so are you saying that Spring doesn't define a "default" `UserCache` bean? My impression was that Spring uses a `NullUserCache` by default if no other is specified - is that impression wrong? And **(2)** say I want to define my `UserCache` bean like so: `UserCache userCache = new SpringCacheBasedUserCache(new ConcurrentMapCache("user-cache"));`. Can you provide a code snippet of registering that as an injectable `@Bean` which I could then use inside my `MyUserDetailsService` (and perhaps other places as well)?

Comment: Thanks again for all the help thus far!

Comment: No, spring doesn't define a 'default' UserCache.  There are just too many user one could cache which i why (imo) I don't have one.

Comment: I updated my comment with a link to a gist i just made.  It a config that'm currently using for Object caching. Doing one for UserCache should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean can be used if a  simple implementation is required.